# Limit the size of the Kismet PCAP output file?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am running some kismet captures, and I need to continuously parse the outputted PCAP files, so in order to do this I need Kismet to save the file, and start a new one periodically (I use inotify-tools to detect newly created files).

But the problem is I do not find a way for kismet to do it. In man pages i found that -m option allows to limit the file size by packet size, so I ran it like this:

sudo kismet -c wlan0 -m 10

But that did not create multiple files, it carried on just putting all traffic to one file.

Any other ways to somehow make kismet break output to different files? I don't really care about what criteria is used (time, packet count, file size.. I'll take anything)

Thanks!